# "Gifted ___ with'' Is it correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, descriptive-grammar

Sentence for example

> She gifted him shoes, to whom he had gifted diamond with

I want to know if *gifted ____ with* can be used. 
The sentence above is just an example.

Comment: I'd have to go with 'no' because I have no idea what the second phrase is trying to say.

Comment: Who is receiving the gift of diamonds? It seems to be coming from "him", which I guess is the same as "he" in the first clause.

Comment: Without _with_, your sentence would sound like an archaic way of saying that she, to whom he gave diamonds, gave him shoes. If you add _with_ to it, all meaning seems to leave the sentence...

Comment: Consider:  *"She gave him shoes."* and drop the second phrase entirely.

Comment: Poetically or literally, and slightly archaically, one could say 'She gifted him shoes, who had gifted her diamond'. But it is not colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is utterly ungrammatical. The first clause is OK, but the rest falls down right with "to whom": it sounds like it wants to refer to "She", but grammatically it refers to "shoes", which aren't a "whom" ("who/whom" is for people; for objects you would use "what/that/which"; in this case it would be "to which..."). "Diamond" is strange; it would usually be "diamonds" or "a diamond", I'm sure there are contexts in which "diamond" is uncountable but they're the minority.

Finally, there are so many things wrong with the "with" at the end of that sentence it is difficult to know where to begin.

A sentence like "[something] [someone] [verb]ed [blabla] with" should be equivalent to "[someone] [verb]ed [blabla] with [something]". Like, "the tools I fixed my car with" -> "I fixed my car with the tools". "The diamonds I gifted my cat with" -> "I gifted my cat with diamonds".

So we have the first issue, where unless "diamond" is someone or something you are making gifts to, you have inverted the subjects in that sentence.

Secondly, the "to" is incompatible with the "with". Take these two sentences:

> "The girlfriend I broke up with last year, TO WHOM I had gifted a car..."
>
> "The car I bought last year, THAT I gifted my boyfriend WITH..."

Those two clauses "translated" into straight subject-verb-object form come out to:

> "I had gifted a car to the girlfriend I broke up with last year"
>
> "I gifted my boyfriend with the car I bought last year"

As you can see, the "to" and "with" in those sentences are modifiers on the verb "gifted": it's not so much the verb "to gift" that you're using, but "**to gift to**" and "**to gift with**". Those are two different phrasal verbs, and you can't use both "to" and "with" together there, it simply won't mean anything. Worse, these adverbs modify the verb in opposite ways: "to gift XXX to YYY" means to give XXX to person YYY, while "to gift XXX with YYY" means to give YYY to person XXX.

Maybe you meant, "She, who he had gifted with diamonds, gifted him with shoes".

Finally, less important but still noticeable: "to gift" is an unusual verb in English. This might be a translation issue, where in your language you have a specific, common verb for "to give a gift" and so you're looking for the equivalent in English, but in English the verb you usually use for "giving a gift" is just "giving". "She gave him diamonds"; "He gave her a car as a gift", "they gave her wine for her birthday"...

"Gifting" is much more unusual and therefore noticeable; you would usually use it if you're *emphasizing* how it's a gift, not just saying it is, or if it would be very ambiguous otherwise. Even seeing it twice in one sentence looks a bit strange and stilted to me.

In summary, maybe you aren't fluent enough in English to pull off such complicated sentences; maybe try and say what you were trying to say in a simpler way.